Reading Documents Directly from Llama Index as Files Instead of Specifying a Folder Path
I'm using llama index and want to directly read documents as files instead of specifying the folder path as described in the official documentation. The current method assumes that llama index users always have a downloaded file in a directory. Here's the code snippet from the documentation:
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("./data").load_data()

How can I modify this to read documents directly without specifying the folder path?

The SimpleDirectoryReader has an input_files parameter which accepts a list of file paths.
This should work:
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(
  input_files = ["./data/file.txt"]
).load_data()


